# Akka context.actorOf not working

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, akka

Im experimenting with akka on the  intellij IDE. Im trying to run the following:

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props

class HelloActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("hello back at you")
    case 'a' => println("1")
    case 'b' => println("2")
    case _   => println("huh?")
  }
}

object FromHere{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")

    val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor")
    val reference = context.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor")

    val input = Console.readLine()

    helloActor ! input
  }
}
```

but I'm getting this Error Message:

```
Error:(21, 21) not found: value context
    val reference = context.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor")
                ^
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not related to your problem but a good tip, you can write all your imports like this: `import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}`

Comment: couldn't i actually do import akka.actor._ ? what would be the benifits either way?

Comment: With one you import ALL the classes in that package, with the other you just import the specific ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have an actor system named `context`, you only have one named `system`

```
val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem") // <- defines "system"

val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor") // <- uses "system"
val reference = context.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor") // <- uses the undefined value "context"
```

Add to that, it's probably not a good idea to have two actors with the same name (i.e. "helloactor"), it'll most likely end up causing trouble down the line because of how Akka defines actor "paths" (`akka://HelloSystem/helloactor`)

If you define two actors with the same name you get the following exception:

```
akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [helloactor] is not unique!
```

Comment: thank you, you're answer made me realize that i need to go back and do more reading

Answer (score -1):

If a `class X` extends `Actor` you should be able to use the context form of creating a child actor. `FromHere` is an object instance and hence doesn't apply.

Comment: `FromHere` is the object in which the `main` method resides, it has no other purpose than serving as an entry point for the program, and as such has nothing to do with the error

Comment: Electric Coffee, you are being a bit too harsh: the explanation is not as clear as it could be, but it is not wrong. The problem that the compiler complains about is indeed that `FromHere` does not have a `context` member. If that is your downvote then I suggest that you reconsider.